# OxyPlot LinearAxis конвертировать значение в DateTime

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, oxyplot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Строится график значение по х от 0 до 1000. Как конвертировать эти значение в DateTime? Нужно чтоб подписи на шкале были не (0, 100, 200..) а (0:00, 0:30 ...). т.е. если длина трека равна 60с то цена деления будет равна 0,06с. На данном изображении длина аудио равна 30с и цена одного деления 0,03с.

Comment: а в каких единицах времени 0-1000 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать ось [TimeSpanAxis](http://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models/axes/TimeSpanAxis.html), которая сама преобразует ваши значения в TimeSpan. В качестве единицы измерения принимается одна секунда.

Вы всегда можете перед отображением данных домножить на соответствующий коэффициент, в вашем случае:

```
double @new = count * 1.0 / lng;
```

где

```
count - длительность
lng - предельное значение по оси X
```

на ваших примерах

```
count = 60, lng = 1000 => @new = 0.06
count = 30, lng = 1000 => @new = 0.03
```

Пример:

```
    public static PlotModel createModel(int count, int lng = 1000)
    {
        var model = new PlotModel();
        var series = new LineSeries();

        //генерируем фейковые данные
        var rand = new Random();
        var data =
             Enumerable.Range(0, lng)
             .Select(i => new { Value = i, Rand = rand.Next(-50, 51) });

        double @new = count * 1.0 / lng;

        foreach (var x in data)
            series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(x.Value * @new, x.Rand));

        model.Series.Add(series);

        var axes = new TimeSpanAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom };
        axes.TickStyle = TickStyle.None;
        //axes.MajorGridlineColor
        model.Axes.Add(axes);

        return model;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вот как раз в этом то и есть проблема т.к. у  TimeSpanAxis в качестве единицы измерения принимается одна секунда, а на приведенном примере должно быть 0,03с.